# Simplest way to transform a CGAL::Surface_mesh

Tags: cgal

I have a `CGAL::Surface_mesh myMesh`, I want to:

1. Translate `myMesh`, such that the centroid is its new origin
2. Rotate `myMesh`, such that the principal axis is X-axis
3. then Scale `myMesh`

I know, that I can use `Surface_mesh_deformation`, but that seems to be in-efficient when I want to do rigid transformation.

Answer (score 0):

We have recently merge [this PR](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/pull/3052) that is doing exactly what you want. It will be part of CGAL 4.13. In the mean time you can call [`CGAL::Aff_transformation_3`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/classCGAL_1_1Aff__transformation__3.html) on each point in the mesh like:

```
CGAL::Aff_transformation_3<K> aff(XXXXX);
for(Surface_mesh::Vertex_index v : myMesh.vertices())
{
  aff(myMesh.point(v));
}
```